# 1d TQFT minus connection =?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, vector-bundles, connections, topological-quantum-field-theory

Correct me if I am wrong but I believe at least conceptually (maybe even rigorously) data of a 1-dimensional TQFT and of a vector bundle with connection are equivalent.

Going into more detail (and consequently making more and more mistakes), a vector bundle with connection allows to assign to a point the fibre over that point, and to a path the monodromy (or holonomy? Yes I am that ignorant) along this path.

Three questions, but closely related:

Does there exist equally layman-ish description of going back from a TQFT to a vector bundle?

Clearly this requires the base to be at least a smooth manifold. Is there known any TQFT-like object (and maybe also connection-like object) that would work in the non-smooth context? Say, for topological manifolds, or even arbitrary finite CW-complexes?

What if one leaves manifolds alone but removes the connection? Is there known a version of TQFT that would work for vector bundles with arbitrarily severe restrictions (say, very-very nice algebraic vector bundles on very-very good algebraic varieties) but without any additional structure?

Two remarks:

Sort of minimal version of the question is whether a vector bundle $p:E\to[0,1]$ comes with any kind of map (relation? correspondence?) between $p^{-1}(0)$ and $p^{-1}(1)$. Vague association with motives comes to mind but that's all my mind offers.

Obviously I am tempted to ask the same about 2D-TQFT. But I am (almost) successfully resisting this temptation.

Answer (score 5):

1d TQFT's are in 1-1 correspondence with finite dimensional vector spaces, and the image of the circle is the dimension of that vector space.

I think what you have in mind is instead the notion of $X$-structured TQFT, aka homotopy quantum field theory. Those are defined for pairs of a topological manifold together with a map into some fixed topological manifold $X$.

So in the 1d case, you are looking for symmetric monoidal functors into Vect from the category $Bord_1^X$ which has

- objects points together with a map into $X$, so the set of objects is just $X$.
- morphisms bordisms between those, i.e.  maps between two points of $X$ are intervals equipped with a map into $X$ in a compatible way, i.e. at the end of the day this is just a path in $X$ between your points.

Now you want to look at this up to homotopy, so the bottom line is that $Bord_1^X$ really is just the fundamental groupoid of $X$, and a 1d $X$-HQFT is thus a **flat** vector bundle on $X$. So not only the connection is important, but it has to be flat.

Now I'm not entirely sure, but I think given a vector bundle on $X$ with a non-necessary flat connection $A$, you get in fact an example of a 2-dimensional HQFT, where very roughly the value on a 2-dimensional surface equipped with a map into $X$ is computed by integrating the pull-back to your surface of the curvature 2-form of $A$. This is basically saying every connection is automatically "2-flat" thanks to the Bianchi identity.

Comment: Many thanks for the correction, and the last part is especially interesting! So, what is a flat vector bundle over a non-smooth manifold? And, could you please indicate (say, give a reference for) how to reconstruct it from an $X$-HQFT?

Comment: A flat connection on a bundle is a lift of the structure group from $G$ to $G^\delta$, the group made discrete. (This is a topological notion, no smoothness needed.) This is equivalent to a representation $\pi_1(X) \to G$ which gives rise to a $G$-bundle isomorphic to your given bundle.

Comment: In general you can always talk about representations of the fundamental groupoid, which are the same as locally constant sheaves on $X$.

Comment: As for your last question, rephrasing what Mike said, giving an HQFT, i.e. a functor $\prod_1(X)\rightarrow Vect$, is the same as giving a vector space $V_x$ for each point $x \in X$, and an iso $V_x \cong V_y$ for every path between $x$ and $y$ which depends only on the homotopy class of that path in a way compatible with composition, so this induces a locally constant sheaf (aka locall system) on $X$ in a fairly tautological way (every choice of a contractible $U$ containing $x,y$ identifies $V_x$ and $V_y$ canonically).

Answer (score 5):

> Going into more detail (and consequently making more and more mistakes), a vector bundle with connection allows to assign to a point the fibre over that point, and to a path the monodromy (or holonomy? Yes I am that ignorant) along this path.

Yes, this is pretty much correct.
You can indeed assign holonomy to paths.
Furthermore, there is an equivalence between 1-dimensional smooth TFTs
over X and vector bundles with connections over X.
Precise definitions with proofs can be found in the paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00967.

> Does there exist equally layman-ish description of going back from a TQFT to a vector bundle?

Yes.
The underlying vector bundle without a connection can be recovered
by evaluating the smooth TFTs at the smooth family of points given by the manifold itself.
The connection is recovered by differentiating the parallel transport map.

> Clearly this requires the base to be at least a smooth manifold. Is there known any TQFT-like object (and maybe also connection-like object) that would work in the non-smooth context? Say, for topological manifolds, or even arbitrary finite CW-complexes?

Yes.  Replace the site of smooth manifolds with the site of topological manifolds
or the site of finite CW-complexes.

> What if one leaves manifolds alone but removes the connection? Is there known a version of TQFT that would work for vector bundles with arbitrarily severe restrictions (say, very-very nice algebraic vector bundles on very-very good algebraic varieties) but without any additional structure?

Yes, this is the (∞,1)-version of 1-dimensional TFTs.
(“Holonomy” is now not a strict functor, but an (∞,1)-functor,
which no longer produces a connection.)
See, for example, the [survey by Lurie](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00967)
and the more recent [work by Chris Schommer-Pries](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.08029).